# Clone model field created with Django faker inside DjangoModelFactory

Tags: python, django, testing, faker

I use Django Faker to generate ramdom data and it works great.

I need to check in a model that two fields `responsible` and `customer` in a peculiar situation are identical.

Here is my factory class:

```py
class FirstQuoteRequest(DjangoModelFactory):

    label = Faker("sentence")
    description = Faker("sentences")
    customer = SubFactory(UserFactory)
    responsible = customer
```

By typing `responsible = customer`, I thought I'd add a clone of customer value but in this case, it's a clone of the function that returns a ramdom value which is not what I want.

I thought of using `@post_generation` like this:

```py
    @post_generation
    def responsible(self, create: bool, extracted: Sequence[Any], **kwargs):
        self.responsible = self.customer
        self.save()
```

But it raises an Integrity error. Is it a way to have this equalization between customer and responsible? Which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came from the name of my method which shouldn't be equal to the field name. So the solution is:

```py
class FirstQuoteRequest(DjangoModelFactory):

    label = Faker("sentence")
    description = Faker("sentences")
    customer = SubFactory(UserFactory)
    responsible = customer

    @post_generation
    def clone_customer(self, create: bool, extracted: Sequence[Any], **kwargs):
        self.responsible = self.customer
        self.save()
```

Hope, it helps!